# Splitting C# string into 3 word chunks using regex or other method

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, chunks

I would like to make a feature where a string in C# can be broken into 3 word chunks like this:

```
Today is a nice day, and I have been driving a car /*(don't laugh lol - not a part of sentence)*/
```

So the first thing that I would like to do is throw out all special characters from string except for numbers and letters.

And once I do that, then goes the breaking the word into a 3 word chunk, where the output in the case of upper sentence would be:

```
Today is a 
nice day and
I have been
driving a car
```

I was thinking to do this via regex, but then again there's LINQ methods and all that could solve this easily, so I'm not really sure which way to choose to choose in order to make this? What would be the most efficient way?

P.S. Also a problem that I'm thinking of is what if a word has 8 words and I want to make it into 3 chunk words...?  How would I then throw out the last 2 words that don't match the criteria of forming the 3 chunk "sentence"?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: How is the question too broad ? I've asked a specific question ...?

Comment: And where is your code trying to solve the problem? Where are your efforts? It seems that you have just listed a requirement and are sitting there expecting someone to write the code for you. Clever (you got your answers now) but not a good question for me,

Comment: The main issue I see with your post is that there's multiple questions (not focusing on a single issue) and you're trying to reach the "most efficient way", whatever that could possibly be.

Comment: The users who have down voted answers, write the reason please, or if you don't know what to write stop doing harm to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string str = "Today is a nice day, and I have been driving a car";

str =  Regex.Replace(str, "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+", "");

string[] arr = str.Split(' ');
int nElements = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i+=3)
{
    if(i+3 < arr.Length)
    {
        nElements = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        nElements = arr.Length - i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(arr.Skip(i).Take(nElements).Aggregate((current, next) => current + " " + next));
}
```

Comment: This is returning wrong result

Comment: And he want to throw out all special characters. Yours example saves coma

Comment: @Nirav Kamani you removed the regex from the solution or ?

Comment: @User987 Check this... It should work according to your requirement...

Comment: I think you can remove `i=i+2;` and just do `i+=3` in `for`

Comment: @User987 Make sure you check your index to avoid exceptions....

Comment: @NiravKamani yes thanks a lot.. Btw. I just checked and it works for the most part. Just there are some  chunks that have only 1 word containing in it.. Like for example a chunk containing just word "driving"

Comment: @User987 that's what i said just put one if condition inside the loop... to determine... whether you have to take 3 elements or less then that....

Comment: I'm a bit confused honestly, the arr.skip returns a string, should I then split it  with ' ' and check how much counts there are in that array then ? :)

Comment: @User987 Check Edited solution...

Comment: @NiravKamani yes that's it, ty so much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Get all words by using regex ([a-zA-Z]+), then put it into array and from that build 3 words chunk into a array or list. 
If you have 8 words you can check if array  can be divided by 3 if not just delete last two or one word. Code look like this:

```
        string str = "Today is a nice day, and I have been driving a car";
        Regex r = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var wordCollection = r.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

        var number = wordCollection.Count % 3;
        if (number == 1)
        {
            wordCollection.RemoveAt(wordCollection.Count - 1);
        }
        else if (number == 2)
        {
            wordCollection.RemoveAt(wordCollection.Count - 1);
            wordCollection.RemoveAt(wordCollection.Count - number - 1);
        }

        var list = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < wordCollection.Count; i+=3)
        {
            list.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", wordCollection[i], wordCollection[i + 1], wordCollection[i + 2]));

        }
```

**Edit:**
Add howManyToRemove variable to check if i need to delete one or two words.

**Edit 2:**
There was a little bug in my code, I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is one of the primitive ways to do that:
You should split your input string by " " which is done by using `string.Split()` function, which splits by white space if no argument was passed.
Now you should just pass the array you have got from split and take by 3 element.
For removing special symbols from element you can use the following `RegEx` pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, where ^  - is meaning to look for any element which is not specified in `[]`.

```
string a = "Today is a nice day, and I have been driving";
var res = a.Split();
List<string> groups = new List<string>();
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
for (int i=0;i< res.Length;i+=3)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        result += rgx.Replace(res[i], ""); 
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {

    }
    try
    {
        result +=" "+ rgx.Replace(res[i+1], ""); ;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        groups.Add(result);
        break;
    }
    try
    {
        result +=" "+ rgx.Replace(res[i + 2], ""); 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        groups.Add(result);
        break;
    }
    groups.Add(result);
}
foreach(var a1 in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a1);
}
```

Comment: Wow that's a big  fat chunk of code haha :D

Comment: @User987 I have updated code to Remove all symbols except a-z,A-Z and  0-9

Comment: It's very interesting why was my answer down voted?

Comment: I'm guessing moderators didn't agree with the question and  put it on hold and marked as too broad it seems...

Comment: I think this regards all answers.